# Angular $http-get-request ID

Tags: angularjs, spring, httprequest, spring-data-rest, http-request

I use Spring Data REST and AngularJs and have a problem with my http-request.
After a successfull request, my data doesn't includes the ID.

My request is below:

```
$scope.getAllHolidays = function(){
        var URL = String('http://localhost:8080/holidays/');
        $http({
            url: URL,
            method: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json'
        })
        .then(useData);
    };
```

For having access to a table-field, I'm using this code:

```
$scope.title = data.data._embedded.holidays[0].title;
```

But in data, the ID isn't included, so that this won't work:

```
$scope.id = data.data._embedded.holidays[0].holiday_id;
```

I noticed, that every get-request for a single table (like /users or /holidays above) won't give me the ID, but with a findBy-request I'll get it.

Please help me.

Comment: it's possible the api is purposefully written that way. nothing you do in your angular code will change that. you should try talking to whoever owns the api you are using.

Comment: The ID of a resource is its URI. So using the self link should do the trick. If Angular introduces other (non-RESTful) identification concepts, that's a problem of Angular, not the APIs.

Comment: Yes, the self-object (find in data._links) includes a link like this one: http://localhost:8080/holidays/1 <- ID. But to get the ID, I have to filter the string, or is there any other way?